# is there any way to open the panel when the swipe event start by user in jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have developed the simple mobile application using Jquery-mobile in Phonegap.In that application open the panel when the swipe is released by user.Its working smoothly. But i want to open the panel when the swipe is start without releasing the swipe.(I mean if you started to swipe,the panel come along with your fingers).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i came up with solution to the above question. I found this https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js plugin.It works smoothly what i am expect.